# Hangman same letter validation javascript only

Tags: javascript

I need help with my hangman game. How do I make an array for guesses and the coding so that if players guesses the same letter that have already been picked, it will output `"You have already picked"+guess+"before."`?

```
 let letters = new Set;

if(letters.has(guess)){
    console.log("You have already picked"+guess+"before.");
     continue;
} else {
    letters.add(guess);
}

// Show player their progress | .join returned answer as a string
while (remainingLetters > 0 && lives > 0) {
    (answerArray.join(""));

    guess = readline.question(name+"'s guess (Enter 9 for lifelines or 0 to pass): ");
    guess = guess.toUpperCase();

    //if guess is more than 1 letter or no letter, alert player to guess 1 letter only
     if (guess.length !== 1) {
        console.log("Please enter 1 letter only.");
    }

    //if valid guess
    else {
        correctGuess = 0;
        for (var j = 0; j < Word.length; j++) {
            if (Word[j] == guess) {
                answerArray[j] = guess;
                remainingLetters--;
                correctGuess = 1;
            }
        }

        if (correctGuess == 1){
                console.log("\nGood job! "+guess+" is one of the letters!\n");
                console.log(JSON.stringify(answerArray)+"\n");
                console.log(JSON.stringify(alphabets)+"\n");
        }
        else {
                lives -= 1;
                console.log("\nSorry. "+guess+" is not a part of the word.\n");
                console.log(JSON.stringify(answerArray)+"\n");
                console.log(JSON.stringify(alphabets)+"\n");
                console.log("You have "+lives+" lives remaining.\n");
            }   
    }

    if (remainingLetters == 0) {
        console.log("Congratulation! You managed to guess the word!\n");
        break;
    }
    if (lives == 0) {
        console.log("Game Over... You failed to guess the word. The word is "+Word+".\n")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `Set` to store all of the letters already guessed.

```
let letters = new Set;
//...
if(letters.has(guess)){
    console.log("You have already picked"+guess+"before.");
     continue;
} else {
    letters.add(guess);
}
//...
```

Comment: this a much better alternative to my answer, didn't even know this existed!

Comment: Hi, thank you for helping it works! but is there a way to prevent it from taking away the lives since its a repeated letter?

Comment: Just perform the check before the rest of your code.

Comment: it said illegal continue statement: no surrounding iteration statement

Comment: You need to put the statements inside the loop after checking guess.length.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to implement something like this?

```js
var guessesMade = []

// valid guess
if (guessesMade.includes(guess)) {
  console.log("You have already made this guess, please try another letter!");
} else {
  guessesMade.push(guess)
  // the rest of your code
}
```

1. your initialize an empty array which you will store the guesses in
2. you  check if the array contains the guess
3. -->

- if it does, you show a message
- if it doesn't, you add it to the array and continue your code